# Aplicações web distintas usarem o mesmo pool de conexão

Tags: java, java-ee, jpa, jpa-2.0, c3p0

Olá!Tenho duas aplicações webs que estão conectadas a uma unica database no banco,como faço para que as duas desfrutem do mesmo pool de conexões?Crio as variáveis do c3p0 no persistence.xml das duas,ou só de uma?               Obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

Até onde sei, isso não é possível. Cada aplicação tem o seu pool de conexões separado. Desconheço soluções que busquem compartilhar pools de conexões entre diferentes aplicações.

O que daria para fazer seria criar uma terceira aplicação que é responsável pelo acesso ao banco de dados e fazer as outras duas aplicações (ou quantas outras forem) acessá-la via REST+HTTP+JSON, ou via XML+SOAP, via socket, via RMI, ou qualquer coisa assim. Ou seja, a ideia seria encapsular todo o acesso ao banco de dados em um webservice que detém acesso exclusivo ao pool de conexões.

Comment: Eu acho que dá com JNDI... mas não recomendaria

Comment: Ok,Obrigado pela atenção!

Comment: Concordo com o Victor, não sei também se faz sentido você compartilhar o pool em sí, talvez o que seja mais coerente seja compartilhar cache através de um cache distribuído, mas isso é mais voltado à performance (queries e acesso à banco), não ao compartilhamento de pool de conexões.